# Eclipse project "MyClass cannot be resolved to a type"

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Java project that I'm working on in Eclipse Indigo. Seemingly randomly (but usually after a file save) the IDE will stop recognizing my classes for which the only solution is a project clean. For example, I have a class `FailedJobManager.java` in the package `com.ccn.sec` which references a `DistributionJob.java` in the package `com.ccn.sec.domain`. When the problem manifests I will get an error in the `FailedJobManager` saying: `DistributionJob cannot be resolved to a type`. The import of `DistributionJob` also errors saying that the import cannot be resolved. If I do a clean the errors disappear.

I don't mind clicking clean once in a while but when I have to click it every 2 minutes it gets old real quick. I have tried playing with the build path order but to no avail.

Has anyone else experienced this before and if so what did you do to fix it?

Comment: it happened only once or twice with me...not regular.. have you tried reinstalling eclipse

Comment: Have you tried re-importing projects from you workspace? E.g., deleting .metadata folder from workspace root (warning: it will also delete workspace configuration), and importing projects again.

Comment: I have not tried either of these suggestions but the other developer on the project is having the same problem with an entirely different machine. This leads me to believe it is a project setting and not a workspace or eclipse problem.

Comment: It does sound like a project configuration problem. When this problem occurs, are there any other errors reported in the *Problems* view?

Comment: @E-Riz Yes, but there are no errors other than the "...cannot be resolved to a type" and "the import ... cannot be resolved". Nothing project config related

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. I have an ANT build that was outputting the compiled classes to the same build folder that the Eclipse build outputs its compiled classes. After doing an ANT build of the project the ANT compiled classes would get put into the build/WEB-INF/classes. Subsequently modifying a file and then saving that file would trigger an Eclipse build that would put the Eclipse compiled classes in build/classes resulting in the build folder containing two sets of the same classes. This apparently created a conflict for the Eclipse compiler giving me the "... cannot be resolved to a type" errors. Moving the ANT build folder to a dedicated folder resolved the problem.

Comment: Would you mind sharing where Eclipse and Ant now build their stuffs to? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @CharlesMorin I essentially left the {project_root}/build directory alone from my ANT script and let Eclipse use that exclusively for its builds. For the ANT build I created a separate {project_root}/ant-build directory in which the ANT script is free to do whatever it does without stepping on the toes of the Eclipse build artifacts.